# How to interpret the ACF of the residuals

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I am dealing with time series but I am not used to it and I am not understanding what the ACF of the residuals mean. I used the auto.arima package in R to find the best model specification for my data.

By looking the plots bellow, the residuals seem to have mean zero and be normally distributed. But what about the ACF?

Also, Ljung-Box test gave me a p-value = 0.05551

[image]

Comment: See https://otexts.com/fpp2/residuals.html

Comment: The ACF is more or less consistent with what you'd see with uncorrelated residuals (you'd expect a couple of autocorrelations outside those limits when looking at 36 of them); in any case the correlations are fairly small and the impact on your standard errors, tests and/or intervals - even if the autocorrelations were not all zero in the population - is likely to be fairly small.